# How to make my validateForm working?

Tags: 8, forms

In a custom module of mine, I have two custom entities A and B with a one to many relationship from A to B.
This is Edit form for EntityB:
[image: Edit form for EntityB]

I want to have this check in validateForm: if 'Contact' (boolean) is checked, 'Adhérent' (entity_reference to EntityA) shouldn't be empty.

Here is my validateForm:

```
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
    $values=$form_state->getValues();
ksm($values);
    if ($values['estlecontact']['value']==1 && $values['adherentid']['target_id']==NULL) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('estlecontact', t('L\'Adhérent est obligatoire quand la Personne est désignée comme Contact.'));
    }
  }
```

In this case, I should not have the error message and still...
What am I doing wrong?
Here is the result of ksm:
[image: ksm]

Comment: Hi, can you check and say if your logic is even entering inside the if statement ?

Comment: It is the case: I get the error message sent by `$form_state->setErrorByName('estlecontact', t('L\'Adhérent est obligatoire quand la Personne est désignée comme Contact.'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!
this works:

```
$values=$form_state->getValues();  
if ($values['estlecontact']['value']==1 && $values['adherentid'][0]['target_id']==NULL) {  
  $form_state->setErrorByName('estlecontact', t('L\'Adhérent est obligatoire quand la Personne est désignée comme Contact.'));  
}
```

Note that `$values['adherentid']` is a mutliple value field. I was missing an array level. Adding `[0]` before accesing `target_id` solves the problem.

Comment: Nice that you found it.
I am not still used to kint. I preferred the output of the old dpm() command.
Lately I am using PHP storm copy path feature in the xdebug. it allows me to copy the structure in complex nested arrays

Comment: @sanzante thanks for adding details to the solution.